# Message with timeout in Visual FoxPro

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I need to show a message in a wait window with a timeout. I have managed to do so with the following code:

```
wait window 'Message Here...' timeout 1
```

If this window is clicked however the message will disappear. Instead I would like to have something similar however in such a way that if the user clicks on the message nothing will happen and the message will stay visible (i.e. message will only close once the timeout expires).

Can somebody please help me out here? I wouldn't mind having something similar (such as a messagebox) which carries out the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to display a message and make the user wait XX number of seconds before they can continue.  If that is the case, then you could do something like this.

```
LOCAL ltMessageTimeOut
m.ltMessageTimeOut = DATETIME() + 5

DO WHILE DATETIME() < m.ltMessageTimeOut
    WAIT WINDOW "Display Some Message" NOCLEAR TIMEOUT 1
ENDDO

WAIT CLEAR
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the Visual FoxPro MessageBox() function. This function has an optional timeout parameter. Setting the timeout parameter causes the message box to stay on the screen for that about of time or until the user clicks a button on the message box.

[Read more about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977987%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: That is actually what I have done to solve it. I was wondering if there was any way where the user cannot escape the message by clicking on it? So it is there permanently until the timeout expires.

Comment: I'm not in front of my PC with VFP on it, but you may want to look at the ON KEY LABEL command. This command allows you to control what the key presses do. So you could say ON KEY LABEL LEFTMOUSE DO nothing.prg. Or you could possibly do ON KEY LABEL *. This will prevent the user from closing the Messagebox until the timer finishes.